# getFragmentManager() inside a static inner class

Tags: java, android

How can I get the getFragmentManager() method inside an inner class that is static?

Why? I'm trying to fix an issue with rotation on my application and, so far, it seems like the inner class must be static for the issue to go away, but when the inner class is static I cannot get a reference of getFragmentManager().

I've tried creating an instantiating a Context object with getActivity() or getApplicationContext() to then do context.getFragmentManager(), but this doesn't work either as the getFragmentManager() doesn't doesn't want to compile inside the static inner class.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: provide it as paramter for your static method

Comment: Providing the fragmentManager as a parameter works. Thanks!

Comment: what does it mean to provide it as parameter ? @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

When you need to access Activity's Context's method in another class, the easier way to do it is to send the `Context` as a **parameter** or directly in the construtor if it's not a static class.

You can also send directly the **Activity** in it, that will let you check `Activity.isFinishing()` to avoid crashes if the Activity is trying to finish itself.